# Why is two-way binding not working on mat-table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating a table using Angular Material.

I want that each row makes available an input field, once the user entered the input, it could be saved with the showed table.

Consider the piece of code below:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="comments">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Comments</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Ex. Homo sapiens collagen type IV alpha 6 chain (COL4A6)"
        name="element.description"
        [(ngModule)]="element.comments"
      />
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Due to some unknown reasons to me, it is not working the two-way binding. I have tested, and the problem is indeed the two-way binding.

Any comment?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You misspelled `ngModule` it's indeed `ngModel`, maybe it's the reason?

Comment: thanks, I have solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Material Input Examples](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples) the input should be written like this :

```
<input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
```

Also, if you replace `[(ngModule)]` with `[(ngModel)]` it will probably gonna work anyway.